# AJAX Error: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with making a POST request to the SendGrid email API.

When I submit the form to make the POST request, I get the following error in the console:

```
Failed to load https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the 
supplied origin. Origin 'https://example.com/' is therefore not 
allowed access.
```

Here is my request:

```
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    data: {
      "personalizations": [
        {
          "to": [
            {
              "email": "example@email.com"
            }
          ],
          "subject": 'Contact form submission - example.com'
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "email": sender
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text/plain",
          "value": content
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

When I add the following line to the data:

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

the error message changes to the following:

```
GET https://api.sendgrid.com/alongurl 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I am not sure why the console is making a get request when I have it set to POST. I'm not sure why this is happening at all. Hoping that someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the **Code Generation** on the [**SendGrid API Documents Website**](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html) I'm not 100% sure but I would check your `headers` too as those might be case sensitive.  `Authorization` => `authorization`

Comment: All JSONP are GET because they are script requests not ajax and they don't support POST or headers . If the api isn't CORS enabled, which many aren't so you don't expose credentials, use a proxy on your server

Comment: I just tried using the Code Generation tool from SendGrid. It basically makes the same call just in VanillaJS instead of JQuery, but I still receive the same exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a request through the browser to the send grid API due to CORS. There are probably many reasons why but the [SendGrid doc explains exactly why](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html) and suggests for you to create a web server to send the request from instead

One reason why from the above link

> When you have a browser-only application that reaches out to APIs, the API key has to be embedded in the application. Anyone with access to a browser-only application can access all of the Javascript source code, including your API keys.

And the suggested way to do this from the link too

> You can create a server based application, which will protect your API keys from being released to the world. Languages like NodeJS, PHP, Ruby, Python, C#, Go, and Java, and others can be implemented to make calls to the API from the security of a locked down server environment.

Comment: Awarded best answer. I was just doing some more research and I basically came to the same conclusion.